# Check if square root is a perfect integer in Java

Tags: java

I get that this topic has been discussed a lot, but other links haven't taken me anywhere on this problem. If someone would be kind and help, I'd really appreciate it.

I need to find out if the numbers square root gives us a perfect integer. And, then I need to count how many of them gave us that. I also have to count all the numbers, which I did that, but I can't seem to get around this one. The numbers are 64 bit (long).

To sum it up: I have to input a few numbers, then count how many numbers are. I did that. And then, find if any of these numbers, when in square root, give us a perfect integer. I hope I'm clear.

Any help? Thank you! :)

Comment: how many of what give you what? count all of what numbers?

Comment: @djechlin I have to input a few numbers, then count how many numbers are. And then, find if any of these numbers, when in square root, give us a perfect integer. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: You state that the other links haven't helped you but haven't specified why or how they don't help you. Let's avoid asking someone to rehash what has already been well hashed, and so please be specific about what you're not getting from the dup link. If it is specific enough, you'll likely get this question re-opened.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels None of them really explains what my assignment is after. I have to create a new class called checkNumber and write the perfect integer and count algorithm there and then output how many numbers were and how many gave us a perfect integer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Of course none will explain exactly what your assignment is after, but you can certainly find answers that help with each portion of your assignment, and then synthesize this information into a whole. You need to attempt to do this first before coming here as this way if you're still stuck, you can ask a much more specific and answerable question.